# Python parsing a table from webpage

Tags: python, html, json, python-requests

I'm trying to parse the table in [this link](https://www.jisilu.cn/data/cbnew/#cb) into a structured datatype e.g. a DataFrame or json or something like these. However it seems that none of the approaches I tried would work out, including `requests`, `pandas.read_html`.

Finally I found it was because the HTML obtained from the webpage did **not** contain the information in the table. For example, the string `"贵广转债"` is obviously present in the table body, but is absent from the page source (ctrl+F it gives no match)! However, this string **is** present when you right click and go to `Inspect` the cell.

[image]

[image]

It seems that if I can get the information in the `Inspect -> Elements` panel then I may be able to parse the table out. How can I do this?

Comment: In this day and age a lot of content is updated via javascript. So the html that loads the page (view source) and the html that gets updated and rendered (inspect) will not always be the same. there are a number of java script events that will modify the page content and that wouldnt be reflected in the page source.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle So what is your solution?

Comment: @DecaK first the OP needs to identify if this is indeed the case. When i have coded such things which have java script triggers or javascript on click events which modify the page i have used selenium for such activities.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle yes this table is the price data of a bunch of actively traded convertible bonds. They shoule be updated frequently.

Comment: Well, you can use Selenium or PyQt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For dynamic pages that load data with ajax requests, try monitoring *Network* tab in *Developer Tools* (F12)[image: network tab], and find the request you need.

Here the ticker data is requested from `https://www.jisilu.cn/data/cbnew/cb_list/?___jsl=LST___t=1561977181934`

```
POST https://www.jisilu.cn/data/cbnew/cb_list/?___jsl=LST___t=1561977181934
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,de-DE;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Referer: https://www.jisilu.cn/data/cbnew/
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: kbzw__Session=7n47d42nc28n259v722k8onhq5; kbz_newcookie=1
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

fprice=&tprice=&volume=&svolume=&premium_rt=&ytm_rt=&rating_cd=&is_search=N&btype=&listed=Y&industry=&bond_ids=&rp=50&page=1

<> 2019-07-01T013533.200.json
```

You can then use `requests` library or any other http client to fetch json (remember to supply headers/cookies if necessary) then use JSON however you like.

## Python

Using the info you can utilize `requests` library as follows:

```py
import requests

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = {
        'fprice': '',
        'tprice': '',
        'volume': '',
        'svolume': '',
        'premium_rt': '',
        'ytm_rt': '',
        'rating_cd': '',
        'is_search': 'N',
        'btype': '',
        'listed': 'Y',
        'industry': '',
        'bond_ids': '',
        'rp': '50',
        'page': '',
    }
    res = requests.post('https://www.jisilu.cn/data/cbnew/cb_list/?___jsl=LST___t=1561977181934',
                        data=data)
    res.raise_for_status()
    data = res.json()
    print(data)
```

which gives you a very large list:

```
{'page': 1, 'rows': [{'id': '110052', 'cell': {'bond_id': '110052', 'bond_nm': '贵广转债', 'stock_id': 'sh600996', 'stock_nm': '贵广 ... and goes on much longer
```

Answer (score 2):

For instances of scraping when the webpage is being updated/loaded dynamically, I would recommend using 'Selenium' with Python. It loads the page in your browser and allows you to interact with it programmatically from there.